# Can not open Android layout files in visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 with Android development support. However I encountered this weird error when I try to open .axml layout file.

[image]

Comment: may i ask why not use android studio?

Comment: Android Studio is somewhat slow compared to Visual Studio and I prefer c# to java.

Comment: then use xamarin studio. https://www.xamarin.com/

Comment: sounds lie a good idea . I will try it

Comment: I could not find the standalone version of xamarin studio. the link downloads visual studio with xamarin. xamarin is now integrated with visual studio on PC

Comment: maybe uninstall your VS and try again? they must have changed that recently, bc xamarin used to have their own IDE

Comment: I spent the whole week trying this